# Zend Navigation & recursive Zend Acl

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I would like to make navigation with Zend_Navigation based on Zend_Acl
below is a piece of my navigation.xml file located in /application/configs dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <nav>
        <menu1>
            <label>solidData</label>
            <uri>#</uri>
            <pages>
                <service>
                    <label>menuLabel1</label>
                    <controller>service</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>service</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </service>
                <attendance>
                    <label>menuLabel2</label>
                    <controller>attendance</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>attendance</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </attendance>
            </pages>
        </menu1>
        <menu2>
            <label>systemData</label>
            <uri>#</uri>
            <pages>
                <users>
                    <label>users</label>
                    <controller>users</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>users</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </users>
                <profile>
                    <label>profiles</label>
                    <controller>profile</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>profile</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </profile>
                <dictionary>
                    <label>dictionary</label>
                    <controller>dictionary</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>dictionary</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </dictionary>
                <language>
                    <label>languages</label>
                    <controller>language</controller>
                    <action>index</action>
                    <resource>language</resource>
                    <privilege>index</privilege>
                </language>
            </pages>
        </menu2>
    </nav>
</config>
```

I dont want to show section which all pages are deny in ACL.

For example if there is user which has TYPE_DENY in ACL for all pages resource and privilege of `<menu1>` I dont want to create and display label "solidData"

The main problem is structure of my menu, because as you see I have various resources in one menu section.

I've try with my own Navigation class extending Zend_Navigation with function **isVisible()**" and "**isActive()**" but I cant find solution.

I'll be grateful for any help

[edit] Look at this fragment structure of my menu:

```
<menu2>
    <label>systemData</label>
    <uri>#</uri>
    <pages>
        <users>
            <label>users</label>
            <controller>users</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>users</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>
        </users>
        <profile>
            <label>profiles</label>
            <controller>profile</controller>
            <action>index</action>
            <resource>profile</resource>
            <privilege>index</privilege>
        </profile>
    </pages>
</menu2>
```

I cant `<resource>` to `<menu2>` because `<menu2>` include pages with different resources f.e. 'users' and 'profile'.
maybe there is some possibility to add many resources to one menu. I try something like that:

```
<menu2>
    <label>systemData</label>
    <uri>#</uri>
    <resource>users</resource>
    <resource>profile</resource>
    <pages>
        ...
    </pages>
</menu2>
```

but i get

```
Invalid argument: $resource must be null, a string,  or an instance of Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface
```

**EDIT**

Ok, but if I change a structure of menu I also have to change ACL.
In my ACL resource is Controller the privilege is Action in contoller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but why don't you have a resource in `<menu1>` and deny these users access to that resource either instead or additionally to the others? You may have to make changes to your ACL schema to catch such a events but not to the navigation.

**UPDATE**
Try this for your second question:

```
<menu2>
    <label>systemData</label>
    <uri>#</uri>
    <resource>systemData</resource>
    <pages>
        ...
    </pages>
</menu2>
```

A resource is just an identifier so you should not (cannot) add two resources to one object. You do not have to worry about access logic in navigation but provide information for ACL to work with. In your ACL you have, of course, to add more logic so you can assign the privilege to the correct resource.

Comment: I agree, add a resource and privilege to `<menu1>` and limit access to that navigation item in the ACL

Comment: pages witch belong to <menu2> has difference resources so i cant add any resource to <menu2> This is not a solution

Comment: ok, but if I change a structure of menu I also have to change ACL. In my ACL resource is Controller the privilege is Action in contoller

Comment: You don't have to make changes to the structure of the menu just add proper resource names so your ACL can find matches. You will have to make changes in your ACL to address the correct resources. There was this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573978/could-not-create-navigation-based-on-zend-acl/6584277#6584277) that might help

Comment: I mean I want move <service> from pages <menu1> to pages of <menu2>. I dont know what you mean saying "you dont have to make changes in menu structure"

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Well, if you move stuff and depending on your setup and your expected result you will almost always have to make changes to your ACL. This is the nature of Access Control and applies to many types of access. If you move your wallet from your room, where you have your key and only you have access, to another room you will most likely have to make changes somewhere somehow to protect access to your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

i.e. Tag the privilege? maybe?

```
       $this->allow($guest, array('login', 'register'), array('view', 'guest:login', 'guest:register'));
   $this->allow('user', array('logout', new Zfcms_Acl_Resource_News, 'content'), array('view', 'browse', 'latest', 'submit', 'save', 'editown', 'deleteown'));
   $this->allow('admin', array('admin:area'), array('admin:view', 'admin:edit', 'admin:delete', 'admin:summary'));
   $this->allow('admin');
   $this->deny($guest, new Zfcms_Acl_Resource_News, array('save'));
   /**
    * The below prevents logged users from seeing the login/register tabs
    */
   $this->deny(new Zfcms_Acl_Role_User(), null, array('guest:login', 'guest:register'));
```